# Inline-block elements vertically align to bottom (instead of default top) for no apparent reason

Tags: css

On [my page](https://goo.gl/pE4fQa), I have a list of elements of different heights set to `inline-block` with a width of about 33% to have 3 per row. In terms of vertical alignment, they should align to top (default behaviour). Instead they seem to align to bottom which makes no sense to me.

What makes them behave this way?

[image]

CSS:

```
.resource_item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 31%; 
    margin-bottom: 30px;    
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
```

PHP:

```
while ...

    ?>
    <div class='resource_item'>
        Content
    </div>
    <?php

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline` which is why it's aligning to the bottom. You can change the value with `vertical-align: top` or other acceptable values

```
.resource_item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Acceptable values for `vertical-align`:

```
/* keyword values */
vertical-align: baseline;
vertical-align: sub;
vertical-align: super;
vertical-align: text-top;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
vertical-align: middle;
vertical-align: top;
vertical-align: bottom;

/* <length> values */
vertical-align: 10em;
vertical-align: 4px;

/* <percentage> values */
vertical-align: 20%;

/* Global values */
vertical-align: inherit;
vertical-align: initial;
vertical-align: unset;
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Syntax